# Force Selenium in Python to wait until the browser is done loading

Tags: django, python-3.x, selenium, tdd, functional-testing

I am currently programming the examples in "[Test-Driven Development with Python](http://chimera.labs.oreilly.com/books/1234000000754/index.html)", more specifically the first functional test.

The key parts of my code are as follows:

```
def setUp(self):
    self.browser = webdriver.Firefox()
    self.browser.implicitly_wait(20)
```

I am telling Selenium to make an implicit wait for 20 seconds until it finds whatever it looks for.

```
    inputbox = self.browser.find_element_by_id('id_new_item')
    self.assertEqual(
        inputbox.get_attribute('placeholder'),
        'Enter a To-Do item'
    )

    inputbox.send_keys('Buy peacock feathers')
    inputbox.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)

    table = self.browser.find_element_by_id('id_list_table')
    rows = table.find_elements_by_tag_name('tr')
    self.assertIn('1: Buy feather peacocks', [row.text for row in rows])
```

The biggest problem here are in the following lines:

```
    inputbox.send_keys('Buy peacock feathers')
    inputbox.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)

    table = self.browser.find_element_by_id('id_list_table')
```

1. It writes "Buy peacock feathers" in the input box.
2. It presses enter.
3. It, *immediately after*, tries to find the items in the table.

The issue is that my computer is not that fast. By the time the items are found, the browser is still trying to load the script, and the assert fails.

I do know that there are two types of waits for Selenium: Implicit (already applied) and explicit (did some research on it). My issues with both are the following:

- Implicit waits are useless because *the items are found*, regardless whether the items are what I am looking for or not.
- Explicit waits are useless because the page is the same both before and after the form is sent, and as such there is nothing to wait for.
- `time.sleep()` hangs the script if used too much.
- Yes, I also checked that `item_text` was correctly referenced, including the `name` attribute :)

What are my other options? What can I do to force Selenium to wait until the page is loaded? Thank you beforehand.

EDIT: The view is as follows, following the example in the book.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Lista de Quehaceres</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Tu Lista de Quehaceres</h1>
        <form method="POST">
            <input id="id_new_item" name="item_text" placeholder="Entre un ítem de quehacer" />
            {% csrf_token %}
        </form>
        <table id="id_list_table">
            <tr><td>1: {{ new_item_text }}</td></tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wait for a specific [text to be present in element](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/api.html#selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.text_to_be_present_in_element) using [`WebDriverWait`](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/waits.html#explicit-waits):

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC


inputbox.send_keys('Buy peacock feathers')
inputbox.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)

table = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
    EC.text_to_be_present_in_element((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "table#id_list_table tr td"), "Buy peacock feathers")
)
```

Comment: I'm trying to follow the example in the book, and the table is present from the start. I edited my OP with the view code.

Comment: @user1231958 okay, gotcha, updated with a new idea. Hope it helps.

Comment: I'm gonna accept your question because I figured out something else happened that is killing Selenium, yet I have no idea what it can be. And, your idea is going to be useful, too! Thank you!